# not able to access the dynamic id in a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var id =123;
```

```html
<td>
  <a href="objectives.html" onclick="location.href=this.href+'?id='+ id;return false;"> 
    <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> 
  </a>
</td>
```

Inside a table `<td>` I have put this code and not able to fetch the id inside the td. Id can not be fetched and not able to pass the id in href.

Comment: <td><a href="objectives.html"onclick="location.href=this.href+'?id='+id;return false;"> <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> </a></td>


This is the place where I want to fetch the id

Comment: I've corrected the formatting for you. Please take care to ensure your questions are readable before submitting them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code works if you rename the id to myId. There is likely a window.id that is shadowing your variable

```js
var id=123;
var myId=123;
```

```html
<td>
  <a href="https://google.com/search" 
  onclick="location.href=this.href+'?q='+ myId;return false;"> 
    <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> Click
  </a>
</td>
<hr/>
Test:

<td>
  <a href="" 
  onclick="console.log('id',id,'myId',myId);return false;"> 
    <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i> Click
  </a>
</td>
```